# Add files to a ZIP archive?

Tags: delphi, zip, archive

What component or method can be used to specify a list of filenames and then zip them into a single archive?

I dont need advanced features or anything really, but if I could add some filenames to a stringlist for example then put those files into a ZIP that would be good.

Ive tried searching a few components but not sure which ones to use.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to VCLZip that Chris mentioned, [Abbrevia](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpabbrevia/) (one of the old TurboPower packages) is available for free at SourceForge. <strike>If you need Delphi 2010/XE versions, you can find those available at [SongBeamer](http://www.songbeamer.com/delphi/) (if the changes haven't been incorporated into the SF tree yet).</strike> As I was well educated about in the comments to my answer, the D2010/XE changes (as well as many bugfixes and new features) have been added to the project at SF, so the SongBeamer version is no longer needed.

Comment: Craig Peterson has updated Abbrevia in the main repository and it contains several bug fixes.   It works with Delphi XE out of the box, no need to goto SongBeamer any more.    It has problems that were resolved by Craig.

Comment: @Robert: I wasn't sure if it had made the main repo yet; thanks for the clarification. I'll have to update here to get those bug fixes.

Comment: @Ken: I've had the SongBeamer changes in the official release for over a year now.  Abbrevia 4 was released in March and added support for decompressing most of the new zipx compression methods, bzip2 archives, and tar files containing long filenames.  The svn trunk also includes zip64 (>4GB) support, more stable splitting/spanning, and treeview/listview components that work together like WinZip does.

Comment: @Craig Peterson: I haven't updated Abbrevia for a while; I'm using it in a couple of pretty stable projects. I'll have to get the updated versions from the repo, though, now that I'm aware of the number of changes. Thanks for the detailed info (and your work on the project).

Answer (score 1):

VCLZip is good, fairly popular.  http://vclzip.bizland.com/  IIRC, it has good documentation and examples that will get you off to a quick start.

Answer (score 0):

I have used sometimes [ZipMaster](http://www.delphizip.org/), and it works well.

Regards.